# How to retrieve metadata from salesforce with force.com toolkit for PHP?

Tags: php, soap, salesforce, metadata, force.com

I want to retrieve the value of a parameter from my salesforce instance. For example, I want to recover the trusted IP range:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_securitysettings.htm

To do this, use the Metadata API. To access to this API, I use the force.com toolkit for PHP.

However, the examples given only deal with the creation or the update of the parameters:

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2011/11/extending-the-force-com-toolkit-for-php-to-handle-the-metadata-api.html

How to simply get the value of the parameter (for example the trusted IP range)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP toolkit shipped by Salesforce is quite outdated and should not be used. There are more recent forks/community projects ([one](https://github.com/uuf6429/Force.com-Toolkit-for-PHP/tree/Major-refactor#forcecom-toolkit-for-php),[two](https://github.com/goetas-webservices/salesforce-enterprise-client)) that attempt to implement a modern PHP client, perhaps one of these will work for you.

A simple(r) solution is to retrieve the SecuritySettings via a plain SOAP call to the Metadata API. The [request payload](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/manifest_samples.htm) with API version set to `46.0` should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Security</members>
        <name>Settings</name>
    </types>
    <version>46.0</version>
</Package>
```

and the response looks like this (*only relevant portion is shown, the actual response is much larger*)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SecuritySettings xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <networkAccess>
        <ipRanges>
            <description>...</description>
            <end>1.255.255.255</end>
            <start>0.0.0.0</start>
        </ipRanges>
    </networkAccess>
</SecuritySettings>
```

Translating to PHP:

```
$wsdl = PUBLIC_PATH . '/wsdl-metadata.xml'; 
$apiVersion = 46.0;
$singlePackage = true;
$members = 'Security';
$name = 'Settings';

$params = new StdClass();
$params->retrieveRequest = new StdClass();
$params->retrieveRequest->apiVersion = $apiVersion;
$params->retrieveRequest->singlePackage = $singlePackage;
$params->retrieveRequest->unpackaged = new StdClass();
$params->retrieveRequest->unpackaged->version = $apiVersion;
$params->retrieveRequest->unpackaged->type = new stdClass();
$params->retrieveRequest->unpackaged->type->members = $members;
$params->retrieveRequest->unpackaged->type->name = $name;

$option = [
    'trace' => TRUE,
];
// Namespaces
$namespace = 'http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata';
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $option);

$header = new SoapHeader($namespace, "SessionHeader", array ('sessionId' => $token)); // NEED: access token
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
$client->__setLocation($serverUrl); // NEED: service endpoint URL
$serviceResult = $client->retrieve($params);
```

You'll need to provide an access token (`$token`) and a service endpoint (`$serverUrl`).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to get this to work, identigral's example didn't work for me, had to do the following:

change `$client->setEndpoint($serverUrl);` to `$client->__setLocation($serverUrl);`

I was using Oauth to login, so you'll need to construct the $serverUrl from the response:
<instance_url> + '/services/Soap/m/46.0/' + <org id (from id)>

Example:
'https://your-production-or-sandbox-name.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/46.0/your-org-id'